# Dual of a Vector Bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

I am not quite getting the idea of morphisms between vector bundles. I read and reread the definition but I didn't quite get it.

Can someone provide me with an example of a morphism between a vector bundle and its dual for instance?

Thanks

Comment: where are you reading the definition from? Why did you tag this under category-theory?

Comment: @magma I am considering the category of vector bundles, where a morphism between vector bundles $E \overset{\pi}\rightarrow B $ and $E' \overset{\pi'} \rightarrow B$ is  $f: E \rightarrow E'$ such that $ \pi' \circ f =\pi$ and $ E_b \rightarrow E'_b$ is linear for any $b$

Comment: I understand this, what is it that is not clear to you in this definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a manifold, and let $\omega$ be a symplectic form on $X$. We can use the symplectic form to define a map between the tangent and cotangent bundles. Namely, we have $$TX\rightarrow T^*X$$ $$(x,v)\mapsto \omega(x)(v,\cdot).$$

Comment: In a similar spirit, but maybe a bit more elementary, a Riemannian metric $g$ gives a map $TX \rightarrow T^\ast X$ by the formula $v \mapsto g(v, \cdot )$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh  So if I have a vector bundles  $E \overset{\pi}\rightarrow B $ with a Euclidean metric $g$ , i define the map from $ E \rightarrow E^\ast$ by $ v \rightarrow  g( v, \cdot)$?

Comment: And this would be an isomorphism on the fibers right? Ofcourse, the fiber on the dual is $ E_b^\ast$.

Comment: Dear @KerryH, my formula was only meant to apply to the bundle $E=TX$. But if $E$ is any bundle with a smoothly-varying inner product $\phi$ on the fibres, then as you say the formula $v \mapsto \phi(v,\circ)$ defines an isomorphism of $E$ with $E^*$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Thanks a lot :) I just wanted to make sure I got it right.